# Get all users and their roles(including name and value) from Azure application using Microsoft Graph SDK

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I need to get all users and their roles(including the roles names and the roles values) in an Azure Application.

What I've done is to retrieve all users and include the `appRoleAssignments`. The problem is that in the array of `appRoleAssignment` objects there is only the `appRoleId` for each role.

Since it would take a lot of http calls to first get all users and then for each `appRoleAssignment` in each user to retrieve the needed data for the roles by `appRoleAssignment` Id.

How can I optimize the retrieval of all users and their roles from Azure ?

I think it's possible to use `batching` and combine the logic for getting all users and their roles(including role name and role value) in to a single API Call, but not sure how to do it.

This is what I have right now:

```
var users = await graphClient.Users
        .Request()
        .Expand("appRoleAssignments")
        .GetAsync();
```

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got resolved?

Comment: This might be helpful for java developers. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72044964/3999929

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to get user role assignment records with app role names together by one API calling.

I can understand that if you want to get the information above for all of your users, that will be a lot of requests and leads to bad performance. I think you can get all app role information in your directory and get all role assignment records, match them one by one by using `AppRoleId`.I write a simple console app for you, just try the code below:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace graphsdktest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var clientId = "";
            var clientSecret = "";
            var tenantID = "";
            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithTenantId(tenantID)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .Build();

            ClientCredentialProvider authenticationProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);

            var roleResult = graphClient.ServicePrincipals.Request().Select(app => new { app.AppRoles }).Top(999).GetAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            var appRoleList = new List<AppRole>();
            var userRoleAssigments = new List<User>();

            var RolePageIterator = PageIterator<ServicePrincipal>
                .CreatePageIterator(graphClient, roleResult, (app) =>
                {
                    if (app.AppRoles.GetEnumerator().MoveNext())
                    {

                        foreach (var appRole in app.AppRoles)
                        {
                            appRoleList.Add(appRole);
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                });
            //get all app role information
            RolePageIterator.IterateAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            var roleAssigmentResult = graphClient.Users.Request().Expand("appRoleAssignments").GetAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();


            var RoleAssigmentPageIterator = PageIterator<User>
                .CreatePageIterator(graphClient, roleAssigmentResult, (user) =>
                {
                    userRoleAssigments.Add(user);
                    return true;
                });
            //get all role assigment records
            RoleAssigmentPageIterator.IterateAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            foreach (var user in userRoleAssigments)
            {
                if (user.AppRoleAssignments.Count > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("app role assigment of user :" + user.DisplayName);
                    foreach (var ras in user.AppRoleAssignments)
                    {
                        var roleName = (ras.AppRoleId.ToString().Equals("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") ? "Default Access" : appRoleList.Find(item => item.Id == ras.AppRoleId).DisplayName);
                        Console.WriteLine("roleID:" + ras.AppRoleId + " appName:" + ras.ResourceDisplayName + " roleName:" + roleName);
                    }

                }

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Result:
[image]

Per my test, the whole request spends about 9 seconds.