# Microsoft Graph API Pagination is not working for getting all users from Azure AD

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, beta

We are using **Microsoft Graph API Beta version** to retrieve all users from the Azure AD using below code. API returns only 100 users in the response and to use paginated response we tried `NextPageRequest` property. But it always return `null` for the `NextPageRequest` property. And due to that it never enters to the while loop to retrieve rest of the users.

Beta SDK version: 4.0.1.0

Code:

```
                List<User> usersList = new List<User>();
                IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage users = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();

                // Add the first page of results to the user list
                usersList.AddRange(users.CurrentPage);

                // Fetch each page and add those results to the list
                while (users.NextPageRequest != null)
                {
                    users = await users.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
                    usersList.AddRange(users.CurrentPage);
                }

                log.Info("Users count: " + usersList.Count.ToString());
                return usersList;
```

Reference links that I followed:

- [Microsoft Graph only returning the first 100 Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56707404/microsoft-graph-only-returning-the-first-100-users/56707771)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

Any help on this will be appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The below code works perfectly fine for me.

```
public static async Task<List<User>> getUsers()
        {
            List<User> usersList = new List<User>();
            graphClient.BaseUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta";
            IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage users = await graphClient.Users
                .Request()
                .GetAsync();

            usersList.AddRange(users.CurrentPage);

            while (users.NextPageRequest != null)
            {
                users = await users.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
                usersList.AddRange(users.CurrentPage);
            }
            return usersList;
        }
```

Check your users in Azure Active Directory Users Blade and see how many users are present in it. And also you can test the number of users if there are more than 100 or not by simply extending the code with $top query parameter which gives 998 records per request as shown below.

```
IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage users = await graphClient.Users
                    .Request()
                    .Top(998)
                    .GetAsync();
```

You can also test Graph API calls in [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge).

EDIT:

After a long research I got to find out that its a bug in Microsoft Graph Beta SDK as it is always sending null in the `NextPageRequest`. But the interesting thing here is, it is sending the `odata.nextLink` in the `AdditionalData` property. So use the below code if you are using Graph Beat SDK.

```
public static async Task<List<User>> getUsers()
        {
            List<User> usersList = new List<User>();
            IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage users = await graphClient.Users
                .Request()
                .GetAsync();

            usersList.AddRange(users.CurrentPage);
            try
            {
                while (users.AdditionalData["@odata.nextLink"].ToString() != null)
                {
                    users.InitializeNextPageRequest(graphClient, users.AdditionalData["@odata.nextLink"].ToString());
                    users = await users.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
                    usersList.AddRange(users.CurrentPage);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                
            }
            return usersList;
        }
```

***Note:*** Microsoft doesn't suggest to use its [Graph Beta version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/use-beta?tabs=CS) in Production as they are subjected to change.

Comment: Thanks Shiva. I have more than 500 users in Azure AD. And I tried the same code provided but still it gives null for "NextPageRequest" property. Also, if I try top(500) then it would return all 500 users.

Comment: Have you tested in graph explorer?

Comment: Yes, I tested in graph explorer and its working fine.

Comment: Which version of beta SDK are you using?

Comment: version 4.0.1.0

Comment: After X HOURS of scratching my head, I came over this posting. THANKS!!! Using Graph Beta 4.1.0-preview.

Comment: However, I used users.AdditionalData.ContainsKey("@odata.nextLink")

Comment: Using C# on the NET 5 platform using the Microsoft.Graph.Beta perfectly managed to get all users from Azure using the first method!

Comment: Do you know Java equivalent to the code you have mentioned? I am talking about IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage equivalent in Java and sort.

Answer (score 2):

I am adding below code so that it can help java developers on this issue.

Its not an answer to this thread but for java users.

```
graphServiceClient = graphConnection.getGraphConnection();
List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
UserCollectionPage usersPage = graphServiceClient.users().buildRequest().select(COLUMN_NAMES)
    .expand("manager($select=id,givenName,mail,userPrincipalName)").get();

while (usersPage != null) {
  final List<User> currentPageUsers = usersPage.getCurrentPage();
  users.addAll(currentPageUsers);
  UserCollectionRequestBuilder nextPage = usersPage.getNextPage();
  if (nextPage == null) {
    break;
  } else {
    usersPage = nextPage.buildRequest().get();
  }
}

return users;
```

This is working code. I have tested for 200 users. Maximum page size allowed is 100. I tried for top(999) and it fetches only 100 per page max.