# Get Users using Delta query does not return the nextLink or deltaLink with C# code

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have registered an application and provided the required permission in Azure and using that application to retrieve the modified users via [delta Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-2-selecting-three-properties).

Below is the code.

```
var pagedCollection = await graphClient.Users
                      .Request()
                      .Delta()
                      .Select("userPrincipalName,mobilePhone")
                      .GetAsync();
```

But the response does not contain the **nextLink** or **deltaLink** as mentioned in the documentation.

[image]

I can get the above links if I test the API in the graph explorer.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta
```

Response from Graph Explorer.

[image]

Am I missing anything here while calling the same API using C#?

Any help on this will be appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

You can try below code:

```
                List<Microsoft.Graph.User> usersList = new List<Microsoft.Graph.User>();
                var users = await graphClient.Users.Delta().Request().Top(10).GetAsync();

                // Add the first page of results to the user list
                usersList.AddRange(users.CurrentPage);

                try
                {
                    while (users.AdditionalData.ContainsKey("@odata.nextLink") && users.AdditionalData["@odata.nextLink"].ToString() != null)
                    {
                        users.InitializeNextPageRequest(graphClient, users.AdditionalData["@odata.nextLink"].ToString());
                        users = await users.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
                        usersList.AddRange(users.CurrentPage);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
```

Reference link: [Microsoft Graph API Pagination is not working for getting all users from Azure AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67122432/microsoft-graph-api-pagination-is-not-working-for-getting-all-users-from-azure-a)

Comment: Could you please let me know how to get "members@delta" from users.AdditionalData? On running users.CurrentPage[0].AdditionalData["members@delta"], I get error  The given key 'members@delta' was not present in the dictionary. I tried adding if condition (users.CurrentPage.Count > 0 && users.CurrentPage[0].AdditionalData != null && users.CurrentPage[0].AdditionalData.ContainsKey("members@delta")) but that didn't help.